# Assign empty string for attribute of html element via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my current spring project, I add the elements for a `<select>` through this jQuery code:

```
function load_options(target, lista) {
    target.empty();
    target.append("<option class=\"form-control\" value=\"\"></option>");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: lista
    }).done(function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.item, function(index, item) {
            target.append('<option class="form-control" value="'+item.id+'">'+item.nome+'</option>');
        });
    });
}
```

My problem is with this line:

```
target.append("<option class=\"form-control\" value=\"\"></option>");
```

when I run the application and open the jsp page, this option is listed as:

```
<option class="form-control" value></option>
```

when what I need it's this:

```
<option class="form-control" value=""></option>
```

Anyone knows how to get this with the jQuery code listed above?

Comment: My first question is why do you need to see the quote?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon without the quotes, the form is submiting to form a not-null value, what causes error when the application tries save the data in the database. I tested with `<option class="form-control" value=""></option>` and no error was presented.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try-- target.append('<option class="form-control" value=""></option>');--

Comment: Well, it is not because the inspector doesn't show the quote that it mean they aren't there. Look at the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gagnonka/2a3282r9/

Comment: @KleberMota Chrome display empty attributes without `=""` while Firefox displays with `=""`. Even if you look at the source code you will know both Chrome/Firefox displays `=""`

Comment: would it be good to write SPACE there? it might help...

Comment: @AshishPanchal i doubt it, except if you trim your value, a space is considered as truthy.

Comment: @AshishPanchal I can't write a space because this way the value will not be null. The value sent to server must be null.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon then why the value sent to server isn't null? should be, right?

Comment: @RahilWazir then why the value sent to server isn't null? should be, right?

Comment: @KleberMota it depend what your condition is. If you are checking for null `(value === null)`, then it will not work since the value is `''`. But if you are checking like that `if(value)`, i can't tell why it is not working.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon How I would get a null value for this check: `(value === null)` works?

Comment: Because `''` is not null. It counts as empty string.

Comment: @KleberMota I do not understand your last comment...

Comment: @RahilWazir what I should do for get a null value?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon what I should do for get a null value?

Comment: `if(value)` or `if(value === '')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a good explanation why this happen, but I can't solve this with the jQuery code. Instead, I modify my jsp code related to the select to this:

```
        <form:select path="${entry}.id" class="form-control select" data-lista="${url}">
            <form:option value="${null}" label=""/>
        </form:select>
```

and my jQuery code to this:

```
$("select.select").each(function(){
    var target = $(this);
    var lista = $(this).data('lista');
    load_options(target, lista);
});

function load_options(target, lista) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: lista
    }).done(function(data){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
        $.each(json.item, function(index, item) {
            var option = $('<option class="form-control" value="'+item.id+'">'+item.nome+'</option>');
            if(option.length > 0)
                target.append(option);
        });
    });
}
```

and this solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for the empty string `''` and assign it to `null`

```
if ($.trim(value) === '') {
    value = null; // or set whatever value you need to
}
```